# kivy buildozer failing with "no signature of method" error

Tags: python, kivy, android-gradle-plugin, buildozer

The tail of my log says:

```
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 33.0.0
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        > Configure project :
[DEBUG]:        WARNING:Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn''t support any meta-data formats.
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        * Where:
[DEBUG]:        Build file '/home/mbryce/farmboy-job-info-submission/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/hfejobsub/build.gradle' line: 26
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hfejobsub'.
[DEBUG]:        > No signature of method: build_c9xl77lb02eyhioqx2cj4uwui.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_c9xl77lb02eyhioqx2cj4uwui$_run_closure2) values: [build_c9xl77lb02eyhioqx2cj4uwui$_run_closure2@6a5085f5]
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        * Try:
[DEBUG]:        > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[DEBUG]:        > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[DEBUG]:        > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

The problem line is obviously "No signature", but I'm damned if I know why this is happening. My Python code runs fine on the development machine (Windows), so I don't think there is an issue in my code, just the packaging process. The function name looks auto-generated and I assume it to be part of the python to java machinery? I certainly don't have any such function in my code.

I'm using a fresh buildozer install on WSL (Debian 11), not in a virtualenv, and I have tried removing the whole .buildozer and starting from scratch. I have run out of ideas and don't know enough about java to know where to look for the cause of this error.

Comment: I have created an Ubuntu 22.10 container and installed buildozer there too. Same message at the same stage. This is two different environments both with fresh installs. Is there a bug here?

Comment: I have the same problem using WSL and Ubuntu 22.04.2..